# Laravel + dompdf. Не работает кирилица

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7, dompdf

Генерирую pdf через библиотеку https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf. Необходимо использовать шрифт `TimesNewRoman.ttf`. При генерации все русские символы изменяются на символы `?????`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Скачать нужный шрифт
2. Переместить шрифты в директорию `\ваш-сайт\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\lib\fonts`
3. Изменить/добавить в файл `\ваш-сайт\vendor\dompdf\dompdf\lib\fonts\dompdf_font_family_cache.dist.php`

```
    'название-вашего-шрифта' =>  
    [  
        'normal' => $distFontDir . '/название-шрифта-в-папке',  
        'bold' => $distFontDir . '/название-шрифта-в-папке',  
        'italic' => $distFontDir . '/название-шрифта-в-папке',  
        'bold_italic' => $distFontDir . '/название-шрифта-в-папке'  
    ],
```

4. Используйте на странице сайта:

```
  body {
    font-family: название-вашего-шрифта;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто в html используйте стиль `font-family: DejaVu Sans;`. Он уже из коробки поддерживает кириллицу, и ничего скачивать не придётся